# Arabic, Russian and Japanese in EE?

Tags: language

I have a client which would like to be able to add Arabic, Russian and Japanese into EE fields.

I have never worked with foreign languages other than French so am wondering if EE works with foreign characters in fieldtypes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does. I have just done a site with entries in Russian, Latvian, Czech and have another site that uses Chinese and Japanese.